# Schema for Flat File

Tags: xsd, schema, flat-file, biztalk-mapper, flatfilesource

I have to do to a transformation from flatfile to xml but the problem is that the flatfile has multiple child nodes and the child nodes have sub nodes as well. The records are occuring multiple times in the file. I had created a schema but it processes only single record.
Can you please tell me the structure of the schema I should create that can process mulitple records.

Here is the flat file.

```
ASN,000589,,0000768,
HDR,0008289,0040294A,LA,00,1570,21,TM,,,M,PE,Corporation,120276,052451,05-00289,05-08299,02,LA,B,011,C,BD ,8,LA,16570,24,ST,,N,GETRO,GETRO,120246,054551,LA,0000568,8018279,
POH,0508289,004024A,1,PPO000199,LA,NP,00,13615,13563,13414,1351,2584,,3598,2900,,,A200,B200,HN,18552,1270,,N,GETRO,GETRO,1206,05451,LA,0000768,
LNE,0005289,00402929     ,1,1,PPO000099,AP,00,8719,00704,2536,DW,3870,DW,CC,0930-01,05-08289,,N,GETRO,GETRO,13246,05751,LA,00005668,2,
PCK,A0722,4786149,100,2536,LA,
LNE,0005089,0040294A     ,2,1,PPO0000199,OP,00,82664,001822,890,HW,3500,HW,CC,0656-01,05-08289,,N,GETRO,GETRO,120246,054551,LA,000052768,4,
PCK,031992,48005,12,8290,LA,
LNE,0005289,004029A     ,2,2,PPO0000199,AP,00,872087,0000859,5744,HN,367500,HW,CD,098656-02,05-08289,,N,GETRO,GETRO,120246,054551,LA,00005768,3,
PCK,04022,479782,100,2872,LA,
PCK,04023,4797288,100,2872,LA,
ASN,000521288,004679294A,000075667,
HDR,000788288,004024594A,LA,00,33758,01,TM,,,M,PP,Corporation,120246,054551,05-08289,05-08289,01,LA,B,011,C,BA ,8,LA,33158,24,ST,,N,GETRO,GETRO,120246,054551,LA,000672767,8056279,
POH,000508288,004029294A,1,PPO000000199,LA,AP,00,1360415,1350063,1346914,13501,258304,,35698,2900,,,D250,D290,HQ,10352,33158,,N,GETRO,GETRO,120246,054551,LA,000052767,
LNE,0005288,0040294A     ,1,2,PPO0000199,OP,00,874402,30001281,33158,HA,377500,HA,CC,098630-02,05-08289,,N,GETRO,GETRO,120246,054551,LA,00002767,1,
PCK,03134,480075,12,8290,LA,
PCK,03114,480076,12,8290,LA,
PCK,94985,480579,12,8290,LA,
PCK,94995,480080,12,8290,LA,
```

Here is the schema I have created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

-<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://Test.InputSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://Test.InputSchema">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" standardName="Flat File" extensionClass="Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" namespaceAlias="b"/>

<b:schemaInfo root_reference="Root" default_child_order="infix" default_child_delimiter="," child_delimiter_type="char" compile_parse_tables="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_early_termination="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" suppress_empty_nodes="false" lookahead_depth="3" parser_optimization="speed" count_positions_by_byte="false" pad_char_type="char" default_pad_char=" " codepage="65001" standard="Flat File"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="Root">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:recordInfo child_delimiter_type="hex" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" structure="delimited"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="1"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="ASN">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:recordInfo child_delimiter_type="default" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" sequence_number="1" child_order="default" structure="delimited" tag_name="ASN,"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="Field" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>

</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>


-<xs:element name="HDR">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:recordInfo child_delimiter_type="default" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" sequence_number="2" child_order="default" structure="delimited" tag_name="HDR,"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="Field" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>

</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>


-<xs:element name="POH">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:recordInfo child_delimiter_type="default" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" sequence_number="3" child_order="default" structure="delimited" tag_name="POH,"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="Field" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>

</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>


-<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="4"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="LNE" maxOccurs="unbounded">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:recordInfo child_delimiter_type="default" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" sequence_number="1" child_order="default" structure="delimited" tag_name="LNE,"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="Field" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>

</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>


-<xs:element name="PCK">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:recordInfo child_delimiter_type="default" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" sequence_number="2" child_order="default" structure="delimited" tag_name="PCK,"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>


-<xs:element name="Field" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">


-<xs:annotation>


-<xs:appinfo>

<b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left"/>

</xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>

</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you also add the schema you have so far to the question?   Hint: The solution is to use the Tag Identifier properties on the Record level to have the values ASN, HDR, POH, LNE, PCK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a schema that parses the records correctly which uses both Tag Identifier and Sequence Groups.  I have not defined all the fields, but just put a repeating field under each record which you can replace with the proper fields.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO64697726" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO64697726" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="complexity" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" child_delimiter_type="char" default_child_delimiter="," default_child_order="infix" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:groupInfo sequence_number="1" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ASN">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="ASN," child_delimiter_type="default" child_order="default" sequence_number="1" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="HDR">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" repeating_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter_type="default" child_order="default" tag_name="HDR," sequence_number="2" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="POH">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" repeating_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter_type="default" child_order="default" tag_name="POH," sequence_number="3" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:groupInfo sequence_number="4" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LNE">
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" repeating_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter_type="default" child_order="default" tag_name="LNE," sequence_number="1" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field" type="xs:string">
                    <xs:annotation>
                      <xs:appinfo>
                        <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                      </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PCK">
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" repeating_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter_type="default" child_order="default" tag_name="PCK," sequence_number="2" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field" type="xs:string">
                    <xs:annotation>
                      <xs:appinfo>
                        <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                      </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Output

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch.SO64697726">
    <ASN xmlns="">
        <Field>000589</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>0000768</Field>
        <Field/>
    </ASN>
    <HDR xmlns="">
        <Field>0008289</Field>
        <Field>0040294A</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>1570</Field>
        <Field>21</Field>
        <Field>TM</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field>M</Field>
        <Field>PE</Field>
        <Field>Corporation</Field>
        <Field>120276</Field>
        <Field>052451</Field>
        <Field>05-00289</Field>
        <Field>05-08299</Field>
        <Field>02</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>B</Field>
        <Field>011</Field>
        <Field>C</Field>
        <Field>BD</Field>
        <Field>8</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>16570</Field>
        <Field>24</Field>
        <Field>ST</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>0000568</Field>
        <Field>8018279</Field>
        <Field/>
    </HDR>
    <POH xmlns="">
        <Field>0508289</Field>
        <Field>004024A</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>PPO000199</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>NP</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>13615</Field>
        <Field>13563</Field>
        <Field>13414</Field>
        <Field>1351</Field>
        <Field>2584</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>3598</Field>
        <Field>2900</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field>A200</Field>
        <Field>B200</Field>
        <Field>HN</Field>
        <Field>18552</Field>
        <Field>1270</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>1206</Field>
        <Field>05451</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>0000768</Field>
        <Field/>
    </POH>
    <LNE xmlns="">
        <Field>0005289</Field>
        <Field>00402929</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>PPO000099</Field>
        <Field>AP</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>8719</Field>
        <Field>00704</Field>
        <Field>2536</Field>
        <Field>DW</Field>
        <Field>3870</Field>
        <Field>DW</Field>
        <Field>CC</Field>
        <Field>0930-01</Field>
        <Field>05-08289</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>13246</Field>
        <Field>05751</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>00005668</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field/>
    </LNE>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>A0722</Field>
        <Field>4786149</Field>
        <Field>100</Field>
        <Field>2536</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <LNE xmlns="">
        <Field>0005089</Field>
        <Field>0040294A</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>PPO0000199</Field>
        <Field>OP</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>82664</Field>
        <Field>001822</Field>
        <Field>890</Field>
        <Field>HW</Field>
        <Field>3500</Field>
        <Field>HW</Field>
        <Field>CC</Field>
        <Field>0656-01</Field>
        <Field>05-08289</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>000052768</Field>
        <Field>4</Field>
        <Field/>
    </LNE>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>031992</Field>
        <Field>48005</Field>
        <Field>12</Field>
        <Field>8290</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <LNE xmlns="">
        <Field>0005289</Field>
        <Field>004029A</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>PPO0000199</Field>
        <Field>AP</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>872087</Field>
        <Field>0000859</Field>
        <Field>5744</Field>
        <Field>HN</Field>
        <Field>367500</Field>
        <Field>HW</Field>
        <Field>CD</Field>
        <Field>098656-02</Field>
        <Field>05-08289</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>00005768</Field>
        <Field>3</Field>
        <Field/>
    </LNE>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>04022</Field>
        <Field>479782</Field>
        <Field>100</Field>
        <Field>2872</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>04023</Field>
        <Field>4797288</Field>
        <Field>100</Field>
        <Field>2872</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <ASN xmlns="">
        <Field>000521288</Field>
        <Field>004679294A</Field>
        <Field>000075667</Field>
        <Field/>
    </ASN>
    <HDR xmlns="">
        <Field>000788288</Field>
        <Field>004024594A</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>33758</Field>
        <Field>01</Field>
        <Field>TM</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field>M</Field>
        <Field>PP</Field>
        <Field>Corporation</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>05-08289</Field>
        <Field>05-08289</Field>
        <Field>01</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>B</Field>
        <Field>011</Field>
        <Field>C</Field>
        <Field>BA</Field>
        <Field>8</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>33158</Field>
        <Field>24</Field>
        <Field>ST</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>000672767</Field>
        <Field>8056279</Field>
        <Field/>
    </HDR>
    <POH xmlns="">
        <Field>000508288</Field>
        <Field>004029294A</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>PPO000000199</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>AP</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>1360415</Field>
        <Field>1350063</Field>
        <Field>1346914</Field>
        <Field>13501</Field>
        <Field>258304</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>35698</Field>
        <Field>2900</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field>D250</Field>
        <Field>D290</Field>
        <Field>HQ</Field>
        <Field>10352</Field>
        <Field>33158</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>000052767</Field>
        <Field/>
    </POH>
    <LNE xmlns="">
        <Field>0005288</Field>
        <Field>0040294A</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>PPO0000199</Field>
        <Field>OP</Field>
        <Field>00</Field>
        <Field>874402</Field>
        <Field>30001281</Field>
        <Field>33158</Field>
        <Field>HA</Field>
        <Field>377500</Field>
        <Field>HA</Field>
        <Field>CC</Field>
        <Field>098630-02</Field>
        <Field>05-08289</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field>N</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>GETRO</Field>
        <Field>120246</Field>
        <Field>054551</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field>00002767</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field/>
    </LNE>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>03134</Field>
        <Field>480075</Field>
        <Field>12</Field>
        <Field>8290</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>03114</Field>
        <Field>480076</Field>
        <Field>12</Field>
        <Field>8290</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>94985</Field>
        <Field>480579</Field>
        <Field>12</Field>
        <Field>8290</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
    <PCK xmlns="">
        <Field>94995</Field>
        <Field>480080</Field>
        <Field>12</Field>
        <Field>8290</Field>
        <Field>LA</Field>
        <Field/>
    </PCK>
</Root>
```

Comment: I am getting the error "XSLT compile error. Root element is missing" although I have created the schema as you

Comment: I am attaching the schema that i have created as well

Comment: I guess the error is due to the  missing  " <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" at the top of the schema output

Comment: @abhishekbisht  Make sure that when you validate instance that you tell it that it is a flat file in the properties, otherwise it expects XML